# How to fetch the pid of all children or grandchildren of a process using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have been given a task to fetch the cpu/memory utilization of the children/grandchildren of a process. Which can be found using `top` command. I have write down a script which will fetch the children of a process but I am not sure how can I recursively find all children and grand children of a process.

```
#!/bin/bash
ID=$PPID
read PID < <(exec ps -o ppid= "$ID")
for _child in $(pgrep -P "$PID"); do
    top -c -b -n 1 -p "$_child"
done
```

I have tried to use `pstree` as well but I do not wants to track light weight process. Could some one please help me how can I find the grand children of the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function list_children {
    [[ $2 == --add ]] || LIST=()
    local ADD=() __
    IFS=$'\n' read -ra ADD -d '' < <(exec pgrep -P "$1")
    LIST+=("${ADD[@]}")

    for __ in "${ADD[@]}"; do
        list_children "$__" --add
    done
}
```

Example usage:

```
list_children "$PPID"
echo "Children: ${LIST[*]}"

for CHILD in "${LIST[@]}"; do
    top -c -b -n 1 -p "$CHILD"
done
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I am not able to figure out how can I add this to my existing script.

Comment: @Ashish What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Doing it in a for loop is slow, try this:

```
grep -f <(ps o ppid,pid | awk '$1==<PID>{print $2" "}') <(top -cbn 1)
```

With this you only run top -cbn 1 once and get the result you need.

Example:

```
grep -f <(ps o ppid,pid | awk '$1==1{print $2" "}') <(top -cbn 1)
 1756 root      20   0  4096    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1                                                                  
 1758 root      20   0  4096    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2                                                                  
 1760 root      20   0  4096    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3                                                                  
 1762 root      20   0  4096    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4                                                                  
 1765 root      20   0  4108    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/agetty /dev/hvc0 38400 vt100-nav                                                    
 1766 root      20   0  4096    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5                                                                  
 1769 root      20   0  4096    4    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6
```

**Update:**  The above command only get immediate child pid, if you need the whole tree of pids:

```
grep -f <(pstree -cp <pid> | grep -Po '\(\K\d+'| sed -re 's/$/ /g' | sed -re 's/^/^\\s\*/g' ) <(top -cbn 1)
```

Comment: `sudo ps`  maybe: `grep -f <(sudo ps o ppid,pid | awk '$1==1{print $2" "}') <(top -cbn 1)`

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your response.

Comment: your script is only fetching immediate children. it is not fetching the grand children.

Comment: I tried your updated command today and it is not giving any output. It worked yesterday though

Comment: could you check the updated script because it is not giving me any output today also I am not able to understand what does `sed -re 's/^/^\\s\*/g'` is doing

Comment: In order for you to understand break things down, run first: `pstree -cp <pid> | grep -Po '\(\K\d+'` You will see that all child and grand child pids are returned, then run: `pstree -cp <pid> | grep -Po '\(\K\d+'| sed -re 's/$/ /g'`, you will see that a space is inserted at the end of the line (actually you won't see that, unless you pipe it to `cat -A`), then you run: `grep -Po '\(\K\d+'| sed -re 's/$/ /g' | sed -re 's/^/^\\s\*/g'` you will see that `^\s*` is inserted at the beginning of the line.

Comment: a regex `^\s*<PID>` is needed so we don't grep for for numbers in other fields in the output of `top -cbn 1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58371/discussion-between-ashish-and-tiago).

Answer (score 0):

You can also combine `awk` with `ps --forest` to resolve all relevant PIDs:

```
ps f o pid,ppid | awk -v PID=$PARENT_PID '$1 == PID || pids[$2] == 1 {pids[$1]=1}; pids[$1] == 1 {print $1}'
```